# Using if b=0 for vector with varying length in R

Tags: r

I have a variable b which is of varying length.

Eg. it can be

```
b=0 or b=c(1,4,5)
```

I have an if condition stating that if

```
b=0 then it should do something.
```

Whenever b is not 0 or is of length larger than 1 I get the warning:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Basically what I would like to have is: if b=0 then do something otherwise do something else REGARDLESS of the length of the vector.

How should I do this properly?

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Do you want it to "do something" when `b <- c(1,2,0)`, or should it "do something else"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `%in%` as in:

```
foo <- function(b) {
  if(0 %in% b) {
    ## do something
    writeLines("Zero was in `b`")
  }
}

> b <- 0
> foo(b)
Zero was in `b`
> b <- c(1,4,5)
> foo(b)
> b <- c(b, 0)
> foo(b)
Zero was in `b`
```

The point here is to check if the thing you are interested in (here `0`) is included in the set of items supplied via the vector `b`.

For the "do something else case you need to extend `foo()` with an `else` clause:

```
foo <- function(b) {
  if(0 %in% b) {
    ## do something
    writeLines("Zero was in `b`")
  } else {
    ## do something else
    writeLines("Zero was not in `b`")
  }
}

> b <- 0
> foo(b)
Zero was in `b`
> b <- c(1,4,5)
> foo(b)
Zero was not in `b`
> b <- c(b, 0)
> foo(b)
Zero was in `b`
```

Comment: would the negation be if (!0 %in% b) ? meaning if there is no 0 in b?

Comment: @user1723765 Yes, essentially it would mean "`0` is *not* in `b`"

Answer (score 6):

There is an alternative solution using identical, any and all.

From your description I would deduce three scenarios, not sure which one you'll actually need:

1. Do something only if `b==0`. If `b!=0` or if `length(b)>1` then don't do it.
   `TRUE` only for `b <- 0`

   ```
   if (isTRUE(identical(b, 0))) {
     # do something
   }
   ```
2. Do something if `b==0` or if all elements of b are 0.
   `TRUE` for `b <- 0` and `b <- c(0, 0)` and `b <- c(0, 0, 0)` and ...

   ```
   if (all(b==0)) {
     # do something
   }
   ```
3. Do something if `b==0` or if any element of b is 0.
   `TRUE` for `b <- 0` and `b <- c(12, 0, 34, 2, 3)` and `b <- c(0, 0, 3, 2)` and ...

   ```
   if (any(b==0)) {
     # do something
   }
   ```